# IE 8 Jquery validation isn't being picked up in MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

So I've a 'Create' view in an MVC page; The input form is generated with the razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
...
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />

</fieldset>
}
```

The strange thing is that the validation works on another 'Create' page with the exact same code.

I've tried updating the JQuery libraries and tripple checked the code, the only difference between the two pages that I can think that might be causing the problem is that one page uses an extra script but when I run with this script disabled the problem is still there.

Both pages work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with this please!?

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it!

I had part of the form generated in another view:

```
<aside>
    @Html.Partial("OtherView")
</aside>
```

In this view I'd re-declared the same form i.e.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Knew it'd be something seemingly trivial like that... hope this helps anyone as silly as myself!